# How does Yarn install decide whether to throw YN0070 and use node_modules vs PnP?

Tags: git, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarnpkg-v3

I have 2 different branches in my project. When I do `yarn install` in one of them, it starts off with:

```
➤ YN0070: Migrating from Yarn 1; automatically enabling the compatibility node-modules linker
```

... then continues. This creates a `.yarnrc.yml` file and then installs the dependencies in `node_modules`.

In the other branch, however, that first message isn't shown, and Yarn's PnP is used instead. It creates `.pnp.cjs` and `.pnp.loader.mjs` files, and there is no `node_modules` directory.

What I don't understand is why there is a different behaviour. When I use VSCode to compare the two branches, I don't see any relevant differences in any files. Furthermore, these branches are freshly cloned and pulled from a remote repo, so it can't be any local changes to untracked files. (Which should remain the same bewteen branches anyway right...?)

My Yarn version is 3.3.0

Edit: I've realised that the difference in `yarn.lock` is responsible for this, but I don't know why.

Comment: Please read the document: https://yarnpkg.com/features/linkers. When `node_modules` folder exists, it won't enable PnP.